# wlan - Can't allocate interface wllease { interface

Tags: wifi

I've configured wlan0 on my Pi, (file /etc/network/interfaces and /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf). In the past I could connect to it with no problems but now I can't. I've tried a few different LANs and I can't get any to work.

Every time I do either `ifdown` or `ifup` I get the result:

```
Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.3.1
Copyright 2004-2014 Internet Systems Consortium.
All rights reserved.
For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/

Can't allocate interface wllease {
  interface .
```

Any hints?

Comment: You **mis**configured wlan0 by fiddling with `/etc/network/interfaces`; DO NOT MODIFY See [How do I set up networking/WiFi/Static IP](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/8697)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same question，you can try remove `/var/lib/dhcp/*` , I hope it work.

Comment: `/var/lib/dhcp/..` contains leases used by `dhclient`.  By default Raspbian doesn't use this, it uses `dhcpcd`, whose leases are in `/var/lib/dhcpcd/*.leases`.  I have noticed in the past removing them sometimes does solve this problem, though, at least with `dhclient` (I've never tried with `dhcpcd`).  I don't think removing entire directories is a great idea though (you suggestion implies this), just the leases, which are pretty obvious.

Comment: Raspbian is allocated IP through DHCP as client，so  I think it should use /var/lib/dhcp/..  -  leases file.Of course just remove the leases should be right,I suggest the whole directory for simplification

Comment: DHCP is a protocol.  `dhcpcd` and `dhclient` are implementations of the client side of that protocol.  They both do the same thing, but they are separate and distinct applications that have **different configuration and runtime directories**.  As I already said, if you remove the leases left by `dhcpcd` at some point but are using `dhclient`, it will not matter because it does not use those, it uses the ones in its own runtime directory.  And vice versa.

Comment: give you a thumb-up.